# destructor is called continuesly

Tags: c++, android-ndk, opengl-es-2.0, destructor

I'm currently working on a game using OpenGL ES 2.0 on Android (in C++ using the NDK).

I have a class called "Drawable" which is my base class for drawing objects using OpenGL.
In the destructor of the class I have to clean up some buffers :

```
Drawable::~Drawable() {
LOGE("release");
releaseBuffers();
}
```

But the destructor is called endlessly (as in every loop of the thread), which messes up my drawing.

I'm kind of lost here and I could not find similar problems, so help is welcome!

Edit: Loop code is here : [link](http://pastebin.com/FJtWZdQJ)

Edit2: I found one of the evil calls:

In my player class I have this call:

```
currentWeapon->draw(this);
```

to

```
void Weapon::draw(Player* p)
```

If I comment this, the spam is gone.

Comment: Do you initialize a new Drawable every tick/loop?

Comment: Can we see the code for the loop?

Comment: When asking your question, why did you choose to show us nothing but the destructor? You've already told us that's being called, so that's probably not helpful. Seeing the loop it is being called in, or that you've done SOME work to determine what about the loop is calling the destructor would have helped.

Comment: @kfsone I did it because I have so much code and maybe it was something simple. Anyways, I understand that this is not clear so I uploaded the loop function here : [link](http://pastebin.com/FJtWZdQJ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are very few ways a destructor gets called:

1) You create an instance of `Drawable` on the stack, and it falls out of scope.  If this is done in a tight loop, the object will fall out of scope and be destroyed at each iteration of the loop.  For example:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
{
  Drawable d;
}
```

Here, 100 instances of `Drawable` will be created and destroyed, at the beginning and end of every loop.

2) You `delete` a dynamically-allocated `Drawable`:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
{
  Drawable* d = new Drawable;
  delete drawable;
}
```

3) You call the destructor explicitly:

```
Drawable* b = new (buffer) Drawable;
b->~Drawable()
```

Note that #3 uses "placement new" and is *highly* unlikely.

---

Objects can be destroyed at suprising times when they are in a container such as a `vector`.  Consider:

```
vector <Drawable> drawables;
for (size_t i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
{
  Drawable d;
  drawables.push_back (d);
}
```

You will notice potentially many destructor calls when you run this code.  When you `push_back`, a copy is potentially made and the original (`d` here) is destroyed.  Also, when the `vector` reaches capacity it has to reallocate, which results in every item being copied again, and the originals destroyed.

---

Objects can also be destroyed at suprising time in the face of temporaries and unexpected copies.  Consider:

```
void DoSomething (Drawable d)
{
}

int main()
{
  Drawable d;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
  {
    DoSomething (d);
  }
}
```

This is a naive example because the compiler will likely elide the temporaries in this case.  But since `DoSomething()` takes a `Drawable` *by-value* a copy of the original could be made.  Depending on other code, the compiler might not even be able to elide this copy.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but neither of the above seems to be my case. I create objects once and they exist till my application shuts down.

Comment: @EdwinSchriek: It *must* be one of the above cases.

Comment: See my second edit, could the "this" keyword be the cause?

Comment: @EdwinSchriek:  No.  `this` by itself will not be the cause.  `this` is a pointer.  Your use of it might be however.  Show us the code for `Weapon::draw()`.  This seems likely where the bug is.

Comment: The code is here : [link](http://pastebin.com/EmjNaNdi)

Comment: @EdwinSchriek: I don't see anything obvious there.  Here's my suggestion.  Set a breakpoint in the destructor and check out the call stack.  You'll probably find something in there you didn't expect.

Comment: Thanks, I will. It will take some time to post results, because I haven't got the debugger from the NDK working.

Comment: I solved it, I was passing a drawable object by value to a method. Changing it to passing by reference solved it. Thanks!